# Optional minus sign for pattern="\d{1,5},\d{2}"

Tags: html, forms

how can i add an optional sign for this pattern?

```
<input pattern="\d{1,5},\d{2}" required>
```

It should allow the input of negative values like -12,48 etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input pattern="\-?\d{1,5},\d{2}" required>
```

Comment: You don't need the backslash, `-` isn't a special character outside a character class.